# Gravity of pyramid effect on person?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, mass, everyday-life, estimation

so I recently just thought of a situation and I couldn't find an answer to why this is online.

The great pyramid of Giza has a mass of approximately 5.9 billion kilograms. I have a mass of about 75 kg. Using newtons gravitational formula, if I were to stand one meter away from the pyramid, I should feel a force of about 26 newtons. Why can't I feel this force? If I stand one meter away from the pyramid and jump upwards without any $x$-acceleration, why wouldn't I get pushed towards the pyramids?

Comment: Expecting ChatGPT to have anything useful is wishful thinking.

Comment: Why take a feeble Pyramid? :) Stand 1 meter away from an enormous mountain that weighs probably *trillions* of kilograms... you'll still feel 'nothing'

Comment: Related to the above: [How noticeable is the gravitational pull of a mountain range?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/267323/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How noticeable is the gravitational pull of a mountain range?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/267323/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Using newtons gravitational formula, if I were to stand
> one meter away from the pyramid, I should feel a force of
> about 26 newtons. Why can't I feel this force?

You are $1$ meter from the *edge* of the pyramid.
But most of the pyramid is further away from you than $1$ meter.
Actually the distance between you and the *center* of the pyramid
is around $120$ meter.
Then, using Newton's formula, you get the force between you and the
pyramid is around $0.002$ newton.

Comment: This makes sense, very silly of me to overlook this!